# Horizontal alignment of text with text box

Tags: html, css

I have a search box and I placed a house looking UTF-8 character in front of it representing HOME. I am trying to lower the house character so that the bottom is at the same level as the bottom of the text box. Now the character is slightly higher.

CSS

```
#home{font-size:200%; font-weight:bold;padding:0px;border:0px;margin:0px;}
```

HTML

```
<form name='input' action='index.php?' method='get'>
<span id='home'>&#8962; </span>
<input type='text' name='q' size=75 required autofocus>
<input type='submit' value=' SEARCH '>
</form>
```

Comment: Try experimenting with line-height property. Do you have a jsfiddle we could play around with?

Comment: @matejkramny I tried line-height adding minus values with no luck.

Comment: If you have a jsfiddle i can probably help further.. Thanks

Comment: @matejkramny I am not that of an experienced programmer. I don't know how to use jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `vertical-align: middle;` for the span and the inputs see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yWvFv/)

Answer (score 0):

Just try:

```
#home{vertical-align: middle;font-size:200%;font-weight:bold;padding:0px;border:0px;margin:0px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/xZPZs/

```
#home{font-size:200%; position:relative; top: 3px; font-weight:bold;padding:0px;border:0px;margin:0px;}
```

Make position relative then adjust the top value to move it down.

Answer (score 0):

because the `span` tag is an `inline` [**element**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente), you can simply use the `vertical-align:middle;` property:

```
#home{[your code];vertical-align:middle;}
```

See the [**live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ch6G7/).

Answer (score 0):

If you place your row within a relatively positioned element and then position it absolutely you will have total control over the placement of your glyph by adjusting the "top" control either up or down using negative (-2px) or positive (2px) values.

CSS

```
.containingElement {position: relative;}

#home {
  position: absolute;
  font-size:200%; 
  font-weight:bold;
  padding:0px;
  border:0px;
  margin:0px;
  top: 2px;
}
```

HTML

```
<form name='input' action='index.php?' method='get'>
<div class='containingElement'>
  <span id='home'>&#8962;</span>
  <input type='text' name='q' size=75 required autofocus>
</div>
<input type='submit' value=' SEARCH '>
</form>
```

You can also play with the vertical placement by adjusting your margin properties

Comment: This solution seems to me a little too complicated, in fact all the elements are inline tag, so you can position them according to their own box model.